# Online storage of content created using TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

We are looking into a means of saving files created using TinyMCE in an Online storage. Does anyone know what are the best options for this.  Is it possible to integrate with Google Docs or the iCloud?  Not looking for a detailed explanation on how to do it,  just any URLs for tutorials on this would be great.